# Extend class to create custom functionality

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, slack-api

I am currently building a bot for Slack using this [slackbot](https://github.com/mpociot/slackbot) package.

Currently, it doesn't have a way to build custom attachments, like for example attaching an image.

Looking at the source, the [`Question`](https://github.com/mpociot/slackbot/blob/master/src/Mpociot/SlackBot/Question.php) class does a lot of heavy lifting to build interactive questions - bundling it all in to an array ready to send to Slack.

I wish to use most of this to build a class that can add an `image_url` to the array instead, but I've never done something like this before and am not sure how to do this or where to start.

Ultimately, I just want to be able to use the package to send a message and include an image attachment.

From what I can piece together, I would need to start with something like this:

```
<?php

namespace //namespace;

use Mpociot\SlackBot\Question;

class Attachments extends Question
{
    //code to add image URL goes here

    /** 
    *   there is currently this function in the Question class 
    *   that builds the array where I need to add in
    *   'image_url => 'example.com/image_url'
    */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'text' => $this->text,
            'fallback' => $this->fallback,
            'callback_id' => $this->callback_id,
            'actions' => $this->buttons,
        ];
    }

}
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction or help me get started with it?

Comment: You can give the Slackbot Framework a shot at https://github.com/iranianpep/slackbot. It's specifically written for Slack and might be helpful in your case

Answer (score 1):

You can get all functionalities from `parent` class by using:

```
parent::toArray();
```

In this case whole function in extended class will be executed. You can always write result to a variable like:

```
$parent = parent::toArray();
```

and you can return it like that:

```
return array (
        'image_url' => 'example.com/image_url',
) + parent::toArray();
```